# SSIS Powershell Pass result to Variable

Tags: powershell, ssis

I have the below Powershell script that is checking if a file exists and is locked.  This is being called in SSIS via an Execute Process Task.  However, I want to pass the result of this as either 'True' or 'False' to a variable in SSIS (called 'Log_Result' that I can then use for a Precedence Constraint.  How would I modify the script to pass the values of True or False to the variable?

```
# checks if the file exists and then if the file is locked

$file = "\\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxxxx\test.log"
if (Test-Path -path $file)
{ 
    try { [IO.File]::OpenWrite($file).close();exit 0 } catch { exit 999}
}
else
{
    exit 999
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the PS script via an `Execute Process Task`? If not, how is the script being run in SSIS?

Comment: yes - as per edit

Comment: You can configure the `Execute Process Task` to use a `StandardOutputVariable`. You might also have to set `FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue` to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution to a similar problem in an Execute Process Task when I wanted Powershell to return a value to store in an SSIS variable by setting the Executable in the Process section to `Powershell.exe`, setting the Arguments to `-Command "& {c:\test.ps1; $LastExitCode}"` where `test.ps1` is the name of the PowerShell script and `$LastExitCode` is what returns the value to SSIS, setting StandardOutputVariable to string variable I created named `User::ReturnValue`, and changing FailTaskIfReturnCodeIsNotSuccessValue to `False` since I was testing various values to return and in some cases the value returned will not match the default SuccessValue:

[image: SSIS Execute Process Task Screenshot]

For more detail on the Arguments section, `-Command` tells Powershell.exe what command to run. The `&` allows Powershell to run multiple commands and the `{c:\test.ps1; $LastExitCode}` are the commands to run.

In the test.ps1 script, I set the exit codes to return 1 or 0. When the package runs it returns the code I set in the script and appends `\r\n` to the value as the carriage return, line feed (CRLF) and I didn't take the extra time to modify the value and this is the result when I ran the test in SSIS:
[image: Watch Window with Variable value]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Can you send parameters to PowerShell as well as receive variable data from PowerShell into SSIS in the same task?  (See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74347107/ssis-powershell-command-help-how-to-send-variables-to-and-get-variable-from-p)  I am hoping someone knows how to combine the two in one script.